# Laravel PHP: Repository Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm still new with using Repositories in Laravel PHP.  I have created a repository file and have placed it in a directory called '**Repositories**' witin my project's root folder.  In my homepage's controller, I have created a '__construct()' function for the repository but when I try to access this page, I keep getting a '**Class Repositories\VideoRepository does not exist**' error.

I'm not quite sure why I keep getting this error even after I use 'php artisan dump-autoload'.  Am I not putting the repository in the right folder?

**Controller(app\OverviewController.php):**

```
<?php

use Controllers\VideosController;

use Models\Video;

use Models\Validators as Validators;

class OverviewController extends BaseController {

/* The Video model */
protected $video;

/* The picture model */
protected $picture;

/* The layout for the Videos and Pictures Overview */
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->video =   \App::make('Repositories\VideoRepository');
 }

/* List all the videos and stones
Included Pagination for neatness */

 public function index()
 {
    $allpicsvids = Video::paginate(10);
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('overview', array('allpicsvids' => $allpicsvids));
 }


}
```

**Repository(app\repositories\VideoRepository.php):**

EDIT: Added the namespace 'app\repositories' to this interface.

```
<?php namespace app\repositories;

interface VideoRepository {

public function all();

public function find($id);

public function findOrFail($id);

public function create($input);

public function update($id, $input);

public function delete($id);

public function forceDelete($id);

public function restore($id);

}
```

**Eloquent Repository(app\repositories\EloquentVideoRepository.php):**

```
<?php namespace Repositories;

use Models\Video;

class EloquentVideoRepository implements VideoRepository {

public function all()
{
    return Video::all();
}

public function find($id)
{
    return Video::find($id);
}

public function findOrFail($id)
{
    return Video::findOrFail($id);
}

public function create($input)
{
    return Video::create($input);
}

public function update($id, $input)
{
    $video = Video::find($id);
    $video->video_name = $input['video_name'];
    $video->video_description = $input['video_name'];
    $video->video_edges = $input['video_edges'];
    $video->video_stores = $input['video_stores'];
    $video->video_order = $input['video_order'];
    $video->video_link = $input["video_link"];
    $video->video_height = $input['video_height'];
    $video->video_width = $input['video_width'];
    $video->category = $input['category'];
    $video->video_project = $input['video_project'];
    $video->touch();
    return $video->save();
}

public function delete($id)
{
    $video = Video::find($id);
    return $video->delete();
}

public function forceDelete($id)
{
    $video = Video::find($id);
    return $video->forceDelete();
}

public function restore($id)
{
    $video = Video::withTrashed()->find($id);
    return $album->restore();
}


}
```

**composer.json:**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",

       /* Added this line below so that my repositories could be recognized */
        "app/repositories",

        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

EDIT:  After adding a "**psr-4**" block of code for my repositories and **php artisan dump-autoload**, this is what my '**autoload_psr4.php**' currently looks like:

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
 'repositories\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/repositories'),
 'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
);
```

Comment: could you post your composer.json file?

Comment: See my edited question above, I included 'composer.json'.

Comment: Hey Jeff, see my last comment on my answer below, your namespace is case sensitive. Change it to `app\Repositories`, or if you still have your repositories folder at the root of your project, just `Repositories`. Also, make sure the case is correct in your psr-4 text: `"Repositories\\" : "app\\Repositories"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the repositories via psr-4 instead of trying to add it to the class map:

In your composer json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",

        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    psr-4: {
        "Repositories\\" : "Repositories"
    }
},
```

You would also need to add your namespace in the top of the `VideoRepository` file.

Also, I would suggest you move your `Repositories` directory into your app folder. This way, your custom code will all reside in the framework's folder that's meant to contain your additions. The composer.json psr-4 would look like this then:

```
"Repositories\\" : "app\\Repositories"
```

And your namespace in any of the Repository files would be:

```
<?php namespace app\Repositories;
```

I would also suggest checking out the [Laracast video on PSR-4 autoloading](https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading). It's super helpful and if you plan on building stuff in laravel it's well worth the money.

Comment: I added a 'psr-4' block to my 'composer.json' file, added the 'namespace' lines to my repository files and then ran 'php artisan dump-autoload'.  I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: Ok, open the file `vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php`. This is where composer writes the actual code for autoloading the psr-4 paths. On the line with your `Repositories` folder path, does it show the folder in the correct location relative to your base directory (the root of your project)?

Comment: I made an edit and included the code from my 'autoload_psr4.php' file.

Comment: Ah, so I believe composer is case sensitive. Try changing your composer.json file so that the case of `Repositories` matches the namespace you've given in your repository files. Make sure your folder names have the right case too.

Comment: I actually have my repository being recognized now.  It was a combination of a namespace and Eloquent repository definition issue.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I ran into a very similar issue when I was learning laravel and got great help on stackoverflow. I'm glad I could pay it forward!

Comment: Laravel is still new to me and I'm trying to figure out the behavior of it.  StackOverflow is great and I try to help people out too when I can :)  Really appreciate it!

Comment: Cool, definitely check out https://laracasts.com/ and try some of the free lessons. If you're going to end up doing a large amount of development in laravel it's an invaluable resource and ultra cheap considering what you get.

Answer (score 2):

Your interface isn't in any specific namespace. Your EloquentVideoRepository is - hence the class can't be found as they sit in the same directory.

Easy enough to fix if you pull your interface into the same namespace as the implementing class.

Also, the psr-4 autoloading should be "Repositories\" : 'repositories' unless you want to adjust the casing on the folder name.

Comment: I tried adding the line 'namespace app\repositories' to my interface but my 'VideoRepository' class still cannot be found :(

Comment: the namespace should be the same as your EloquentVideoRepository class is : namespace Repositories;

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's not being autoloaded, you need to add it to composer.json.

You can add it to the autoload/classmap array or take a look at using [PSR autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).

Comment: In my 'composer.json' file, I added to the 'classmap' block "app/repositories", saved the file and then ran 'php artisan dump-autoload' but I still keep getting the same error.